# WebKit running on a worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, webkit

I have a C++ application that needs to render HTML on a thread.  I have researched both QtWebKit and Webkit2Gtk+ and have run into the same problem: after about 3-4 iterations, it crashes.

The basic setup is this (using Webkit2Gtk+ in this example):

```
WebKitWebView *HtmlView;

void destroyHtmlWindowCb( GtkWidget *widget, GtkWidget *window ) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

gboolean closeHtmlViewCb( WebKitWebView *webView, GtkWidget *window ) {
    webkit_web_view_stop_loading( webView );
    gtk_widget_destroy( window );
    return true;
}

void RendererThread( boost::barrier &render_barrier ) {
    gtk_init( nullptr, nullptr );
    GtkWidget *HtmlWindow;

    while( true ) {
        render_barrier.count_down_and_wait();

        HtmlWindow = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
        HtmlView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());

        g_signal_connect( HtmlView, "close", G_CALLBACK(closeHtmlViewCb), HtmlWindow );
        g_signal_connect( HtmlWindow, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroyHtmlWindowCb), nullptr );

        gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER(HtmlWindow), GTK_WIDGET(HtmlView) );
        gtk_widget_show( GTK_WIDGET(HtmlView) );

        webkit_web_view_load_uri( HtmlView, "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" );

        gtk_window_set_default_size( GTK_WINDOW(HtmlWindow), 1920, 1080 );
        gtk_window_fullscreen( GTK_WINDOW(HtmlWindow) );
        gtk_widget_show( HtmlWindow );

        std::cout << "Calling gtk_main()" << std::endl;
        gtk_main();
    }
}

void EventHandlerThread( boost::barrier &render_barrier ) {
    while( true ) {
        render_barrier.count_down_and_wait();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 15 ) );

        g_signal_emit_by_name( HtmlView, "close" );
    }
}

int main() {
    boost::barrier render_barrier( 2 );

    std::thread Renderer( RendererThread, std::ref(render_barrier) );
    Renderer.detach();

    std::thread EventHandler( EventHandlerThread, std::ref(render_barrier) );
    EventHandler.detach();

    //... sleep forever as far as this example is concerned

    return 0;
}
```

This is a very stripped-down version of the real program, but any race conditions/thread-safety issues should be represented accurately.

The program would always crash at the call to gtk_main(), with this being produced in stderr:

```
...
Calling gtk_main()
...
Calling gtk_main()
Error sending IPC message: Connection reset by peer
Nov 30 16:27:50 gmbase xinit[9541]: /usr/bin/xinit: connection to X server lost
Nov 30 16:27:50 gmbase org.a11y.atspi.Registry[9561]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
Nov 30 16:27:50 gmbase org.a11y.atspi.Registry[9561]: after 21 requests (19 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Nov 30 16:27:50 gmbase xinit[9541]: waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Nov 30 16:27:50 gmbase systemd-coredump[9646]: Process 9545 (glassmedia-debu) of user 0 dumped core.

Stack trace of thread 9548:
#0  0x00007fcbe0e22970 _ZNK3WTF10StringImpl12hashSlowCaseEv (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#1  0x00007fcbe0e15bf8 _ZN3WTF9HashTableIPNS_10StringImplES2_NS_17IdentityExtractorENS_10StringHashENS_10HashTraitsIS2_EES6_E6rehashEjPS2_ (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#2  0x00007fcbe0e14c3b _ZN3WTF16AtomicStringImpl11addSlowCaseERNS_10StringImplE (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#3  0x00007fcbe36fc4ee n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#4  0x00007fcbe372dd63 n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#5  0x00007fcbe374dfdc n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#6  0x00007fcbe3719743 n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#7  0x00007fcbe3719aec n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#8  0x00007fcbe39c6f13 n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#9  0x00007fcbe3704359 n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#10 0x00007fcbe37c4ae2 n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#11 0x00007fcbe370057b n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#12 0x00007fcbe3700f9b n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#13 0x00007fcbe4dea28f n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
#14 0x00007fcbe0e3591c _ZN3WTF15GMainLoopSource12voidCallbackEv (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#15 0x00007fcbe0e342ba _ZN3WTF15GMainLoopSource18voidSourceCallbackEPS0_ (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#16 0x00007fcbe0352c7a g_main_context_dispatch (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#17 0x00007fcbe0353020 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#18 0x00007fcbe0353342 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#19 0x00007fcbe2af32a5 gtk_main (libgtk-3.so.0)
#20 0x0000000000477ec9 _ZN10Glassmedia7Display6renderEv (glassmedia-debug)
#21 0x0000000000498dd9 _ZN10Glassmedia14RendererThreadESt10shared_ptrINS_7DisplayEERN5boost7barrierE (glassmedia-debug)
#22 0x0000000000460739 _ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvSt10shared_ptrIN10Glassmedia7DisplayEERN5boost7barrierEES3_St17reference_wrapperIS5_EEE9_M_invokeIJLm0ELm1EEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIJXspT_EEE (glassmedia-debug)
#23 0x00007fcbe0040350 execute_native_thread_routine (libstdc++.so.6)
#24 0x00007fcbdf85d4a4 start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
#25 0x00007fcbdf59b13d __clone (libc.so.6)

Stack trace of thread 9549:
#0  0x00007fcbdf86307f pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (libpthread.so.0)
#1  0x00007fcbe003aefc __gthread_cond_wait (libstdc++.so.6)
#2  0x00000000004991c3 _ZN10Glassmedia18EventHandlerThreadESt10shared_ptrINS_7DisplayEERNS_12EventCourierERN5boost7barrierE (glassmedia-debug)
#3  0x0000000000460801 _ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvSt10shared_ptrIN10Glassmedia7DisplayEERNS1_12EventCourierERN5boost7barrierEES3_St17reference_wrapperIS4_ESB_IS7_EEE9_M_invokeIJLm0ELm1ELm2EEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIJXspT_EEE (glassmedia-debug)
#4  0x00007fcbe0040350 execute_native_thread_routine (libstdc++.so.6)
#5  0x00007fcbdf85d4a4 start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
#6  0x00007fcbdf59b13d __clone (libc.so.6)

Stack trace of thread 9566:
#0  0x00007fcbdf59218d poll (libc.so.6)
#1  0x00007fcbe0352fbc n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#2  0x00007fcbe0353342 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#3  0x00007fcbe0e05dd5 n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#4  0x00007fcbe0e325fa n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#5  0x00007fcbdf85d4a4 start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
#6  0x00007fcbdf59b13d __clone (libc.so.6)

Stack trace of thread 9567:
#0  0x00007fcbdf59218d poll (libc.so.6)
#1  0x00007fcbe0352fbc n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#2  0x00007fcbe0353342 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#3  0x00007fcbe0e05dd5 n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#4  0x00007fcbe0e325fa n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#5  0x00007fcbdf85d4a4 start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
#6  0x00007fcbdf59b13d __clone (libc.so.6)

Stack trace of thread 9639:
#0  0x00007fcbdf86665d __nanosleep (libpthread.so.0)
#1  0x00007fcbe0e41b3c _ZN7bmalloc4Heap8scavengeERSt11unique_lockINS_11StaticMutexEENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1000EEEE (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#2  0x00007fcbe0e41c5f _ZN7bmalloc4Heap18concurrentScavengeEv (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#3  0x00007fcbe0e429ae _ZN7bmalloc9AsyncTaskINS_4HeapEMS1_FvvEE13threadRunLoopEv (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#4  0x00007fcbe0040350 execute_native_thread_routine (libstdc++.so.6)
#5  0x00007fcbdf85d4a4 start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
#6  0x00007fcbdf59b13d __clone (libc.so.6)

Stack trace of thread 9545:
#0  0x00007fcbdf85e70d pthread_join (libpthread.so.0)
#1  0x00007fcbe0040267 __gthread_join (libstdc++.so.6)
#2  0x000000000045ed55 main (glassmedia-debug)
#3  0x00007fcbdf4d2610 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
#4  0x000000000045dc79 _start (glassmedia-debug)

Stack trace of thread 9569:
#0  0x00007fcbdf59218d poll (libc.so.6)
#1  0x00007fcbe0352fbc n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#2  0x00007fcbe0353342 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#3  0x00007fcbe0e05dd5 n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#4  0x00007fcbe0e325fa n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#5  0x00007fcbdf85d4a4 start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
#6  0x00007fcbdf59b13d __clone (libc.so.6)

Stack trace of thread 9547:
#0  0x00007fcbdf59b733 epoll_wait (libc.so.6)
#1  0x00007fcbe6298f15 n/a (libev.so.4)
#2  0x00007fcbe629b4b9 ev_run (libev.so.4)
#3  0x000000000047e7c1 ev_loop (glassmedia-debug)
#4  0x0000000000498ae4 _ZN10Glassmedia21EventSubscriberThreadERNS_12EventCourierE (glassmedia-debug)
#5  0x000000000045f086 _ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvRN10Glassmedia12EventCourierEESt17reference_wrapperIS1_EEE9_M_invokeIJLm0EEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIJXspT_EEE (glassmedia-debug)
#6  0x00007fcbe0040350 execute_native_thread_routine (libstdc++.so.6)
#7  0x00007fcbdf85d4a4 start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
#8  0x00007fcbdf59b13d __clone (libc.so.6)

Stack trace of thread 9572:
#0  0x00007fcbdf59218d poll (libc.so.6)
#1  0x00007fcbe0352fbc n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#2  0x00007fcbe0353342 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0)
#3  0x00007fcbe0e05dd5 n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#4  0x00007fcbe0e325fa n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
#5  0x00007fcbdf85d4a4 start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
#6  0x00007fcbdf59b13d __clone (libc.so.6)
```

The code for the QtWebKit was very similar; same results.

In the real program, my test looped between Reddit and CNN.  No pattern could be discerned as far as one website producing the crash over the other.

Please disregard anything that looks silly about having the main thread wait forever.  In the real program I have my reasons.

Thank you for any help on this problem.  I have been working at it for much too long now.

Comment: I have a simmilar issue, but I don't have the option to switch to QWebEngine. If you know of something related, please let me know. Thanks for writing this up.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the issue went away as soon as I used QWebEngine (the Google Chrome fork of QtWebKit) instead.  The code became much simpler as well:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>

QWebEngineView *HtmlView;

void RendererThread( boost::barrier &render_barrier, int main_argc, char **main_argv ) {
    QApplication app( main_argc, main_argv );

    while( true ) {
        render_barrier.count_down_and_wait();

        HtmlView = new QWebEngineView();
        HtmlView->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );

        HtmlView->load( QUrl( "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" ) );

        HtmlView->resize( 1920, 1080 );
        HtmlView->raise();
        HtmlView->move( 0, 0 );

        HtmlView->showFullscreen();

        app.exec();
    }
}

void EventHandlerThread( boost::barrier &render_barrier ) {
    while( true ) {
        render_barrier.count_down_and_wait();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 15 ) );

        HtmlView->stop();
        HtmlView->close();
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    boost::barrier render_barrier( 2 );

    std::thread Renderer( RendererThread, std::ref(render_barrier), argc, argv );
    Renderer.detach();

    std::thread EventHandler( EventHandlerThread, std::ref(render_barrier) );
    EventHandler.detach();

    //... sleep forever as far as this example is concerned

    return 0;
}
```

I installed QWebEngine on Arch Linux under package qt5-webengine.

The program will need the cflags and libs from Qt5WebEngineWidgets to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall `pkg-config --cflags Qt5WebEngineWidgets` webkit_test.cpp -o webkit_test `pkg-config --libs Qt5WebEngineWidgets` -pthread
```